# Php echo vs jsp style

Tags: php, performance

Which is the fastest:

```
$content = "some html";
<div><?php echo $content?></div>
```

or

```
$content = "some html";
<div><?=$content?></div>
```

?

Comment: Hm. Test it? Should be really easy to do.

Comment: Using savetime; execute; savetime2; savetime2 - savetime1 ? I'm looking for a more concise answer actually :). But yea thanks :)

Comment: It seems that it doesn't matters. See this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437144/php-opening-closing-tags-performance

Comment: You ask "Which is fastest?" We can sit here and have a thought exercise and come up with a theory but the proof is in the pudding, as they say. Concise answers are formed from performing the actual testing/profiling/benchmarking!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't matter.

`<?= ... ?>` won't work if [`short_open_tag`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag)s are disabled and the version of php is older than version 5.4 though (which is unlikely).

But if you want maximum compatibility, use the `<?php echo ...; ?>` style.

Comment: It doesn't even matter in large scale apps? I'm gathering as many details as possible on optimizing these kind of tiny things to tune my end result :)

Comment: @CoolStraw: I used to be like you, worrying about every detail like this. Then I realized that 95% of request time is spent in the database and small optimizations like this won't matter. Trust me, this isn't worth your time. The difference, if it exists, is negligible. It might save you a total of a minute of processing time over the course of a year. Read the second half of this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437144/php-opening-closing-tags-performance/2437413#2437413

Comment: What is more important, especially with "little" things like this, is code consistency and readability.

Comment: I'm taking all the options into account. That is because the app I'm going to build is bigger than all that I've done so far. That's why I'm kinda worried, and I'm also getting documented... that's how we evolve and become stronger ;).

Answer (score 1):

no difference you could possibly ever notice.  However, `<?= ... ?>` may not work across all servers because short tags is a setting that must be enabled. So you should as a best practice stick to `<?php...?>`

Answer (score 0):

There would be no difference between full and short tags in terms of performance, but I recommend you utilize the full tags in case short tags are disabled.  Additionally you can use single quotes '' if you are not echoeing any PHP variables.

Traditional echo statement

```
<?php echo "Hello World!"; ?>
```

Faster echo

```
<?php echo 'Hello World!'; ?>
```

If using PHP Variables

```
<?php echo 'Hello ' . $world; ?>
```

Or using a comma

```
<?php echo 'Hello ', $world; ?>
```