# Magento template files calling <?PHP ?> for every line

Tags: php, magento

First off I will say that I am new to Magento but not new to PHP.  The question I have is why are there start and stop PHP calls for every line in the template files within Magento  and is there a performance hit for doing so.

Here is an example:

```
<ul class="links<?php if($iecheckout):?> <?php echo $iecheckout ?><?php endif;?>"<?php if($this->getName()): ?> id="<?php echo $this->getName() ?>"<?php endif;?>>
<?php foreach($_links as $_link): ?>
    <?php if ($_link instanceof Mage_Core_Block_Abstract):?>
        <?php echo $_link->toHtml() ?>
    <?php else: ?>
        <li<?php if($_link->getIsFirst()||$_link->getIsLast()): ?> class="<?php if($_link->getIsFirst()): ?>first<?php endif; ?><?php if($_link->getIsLast()): ?> last<?php endif; ?>"<?php endif; ?> <?php echo $_link->getLiParams() ?>><?php echo $_link->getBeforeText() ?><a href="<?php echo $_link->getUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_link->getTitle() ?>" <?php echo $_link->getAParams() ?>><?php echo $_link->getLabel() ?></a><?php echo $_link->getAfterText() ?></li>
    <?php endif;?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

so in this example, there are a lot of start and stops of the  around sections that do not need to be broken up. for example with the last two lines, why call put the  on each line?  Is this apart to how the system reads these files?  While I know it has to increase file space (all be it minimally but with 18k files it adds up), does it take PHP longer to interpret these files when you are starting the PHP tags and stopping them over and over again.   Magento is a huge system and I am sure any performance increase could be helpful.

would it not make more sense to have the block

```
<?php foreach($_links as $_link): ?>
    <?php if ($_link instanceof Mage_Core_Block_Abstract):?>
        <?php echo $_link->toHtml() ?>
    <?php else: ?>
        <li<?php if($_link->getIsFirst()||$_link->getIsLast()): ?> class="<?php if($_link->getIsFirst()): ?>first<?php endif; ?><?php if($_link->getIsLast()): ?> last<?php endif; ?>"<?php endif; ?> <?php echo $_link->getLiParams() ?>><?php echo $_link->getBeforeText() ?><a href="<?php echo $_link->getUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_link->getTitle() ?>" <?php echo $_link->getAParams() ?>><?php echo $_link->getLabel() ?></a><?php echo $_link->getAfterText() ?></li>
    <?php endif;?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

look like

```
<?php 
foreach($_links as $_link): 
    if ($_link instanceof Mage_Core_Block_Abstract):
         echo $_link->toHtml() 
    else:
    ?> 
        <li<?php if($_link->getIsFirst()||$_link->getIsLast()): ?> class="<?php if($_link->getIsFirst()): ?>first<?php endif; ?><?php if($_link->getIsLast()): ?> last<?php endif; ?>"<?php endif; ?> <?php echo $_link->getLiParams() ?>><?php echo $_link->getBeforeText() ?><a href="<?php echo $_link->getUrl() ?>" title="<?php echo $_link->getTitle() ?>" <?php echo $_link->getAParams() ?>><?php echo $_link->getLabel() ?></a><?php echo $_link->getAfterText() ?></li>
    <?php 
    endif;
endforeach; ?>
```

Does this make sense?  Is this just to mimic some HTML type layout?  As I get more used to this system, should I be writing templates in this manor even though it looks like it is harder to read?

Thanks for any information anyone can give.

Comment: yes, it would make more sense the way you've done it... but then, it wouldn't really be a template any more. I guess the question is: Are you programming or templating?

Comment: The crux of this question appears to be: "Does opening and closing PHP tags all the time hit on performance?" which may be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437144/php-opening-closing-tags-performance

Comment: I agree with the two other comments, doing it in this way is better for templates because it's quicker and easier to chop up as required. Otherwise you'd have to physically break up all the foreach statements etc.

Comment: IMHO I hate this form of templateing ...  i think people refer to this as PHTML  and I find it terribly hard to read i use http://www.smarty.net/ for my templating but I don't think you could switch to that in magento but I not that familiar with magento

Comment: Part of my question (which I guess I did not get across well) was if Magento required this to process these template files but I am gathering not and this is more of a design choice.  This example is pretty simplified compared to some of the templates and coming from a more programming background, I found it harder to read.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason I use the following in **templates** (not the controllers, models, etc):

```
<?php if ($condition): ?>
    <?php foreach($items as $item): ?>

    <?php endforeach ?>
<?php endif ?>
```

Instead of:

```
<?php if ($condition):
    foreach($items as $item): ?>

<?php endforeach;
endif; ?>
```

Is purely for readability.

As for performance impact from opening and close tags goes, which appears to be what your question boils down to, you might want to checkout [Opening/closing tags & performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437144/php-opening-closing-tags-performance).

Comment: thank you for the link.  I read it and it was helpful.  I think the point on why would you write them this was is mostly by choice not by system restriction.