# PHP coding convention and efficiency

Tags: php, performance

Consider

```
<a href="<?php echo $url;?>"><?php echo $name;?></a>
```

and compare with

```
<?php echo "<a href=\"{$url}\">{$name}</a>";?>
```

then consider hundreds of these in different variations on the same page.

> Does one or the other convention affect
>   performance in any way or is it just a matter of preference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question has been addressed quite well before: [Opening/closing tags & performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437144/php-opening-closing-tags-performance)

In brief, here is the answer:

```
3 simple rules for you to get it right:

 - No syntax issue can affect performance. Data manipulation does.
 - Speak of performance only backed with results of profiling.
 - Premature optimization is the root of all evil
```

Comment: +1 for "premature optimization". But this are not only syntax issues, because of the several context switches between php and inline-html.

Comment: I've noticed that my question might be a duplicate, I just re-frased the question differently and did not find it. Mayhaps it should be deleted.

Answer (score 2):

It *may* affect the performance, but that should never be the point to influence how you write good and readable code. The difference is negligible.

Just my 2 cent: The first one is much more readable, if I have huge parts of html and I just want to integrate some variables. The second one is more readable, if its only a single line or something.

Answer (score 2):

The single quotes (') is more faster than double quotes ("), because the parser don't try to find variables in the string.
So, I think that the first script is the best way.

Answer (score 1):

The first example will be *slightly* faster because using PHP to echo content adds a tiny latency over just displaying text using raw html.
However, this difference is not noticeable at all and I would advise you to use choose whichever you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

Some conventions can possibly effect performance if they are calling different functions or if they take up more space (so the script physically takes up more space in memory) - but this is completely negligible and just a matter of preference. If you compare it to something like Smarty or another Templating system - that on the other hand will effect performance.