# PHP foreach help

Tags: php, foreach

I am building an extention to my site that allows users to favourite posts, I am however having a a problem,

I am running this code in my view,

```
<?php if(isset($favourites)) : ?>
  <?php foreach ($favourites as $fav) : ?>
    <a href="/favourites/save_feed/<?php echo $f['feed_id']; ?>" class="<?php echo ($f['feed_id'] == $fav['feed']) ? 'faved' : 'fave'; ?>">Fave</a>
  <?php endforeach;?>
<?php else : ?>
  <a href="/favourites/save_feed/<?php echo $j['feed_id']; ?>" class="fave">Fave</a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

However my problem is that if there are two posts marked as a favourite it will loop over both entries and show the favourite link twice on one post, how can I make it so it loops through the posts and adds a favourite link if that post is indeed a favourite?

Comment: not sure if performance wise, opening and closing the <?php ?> that often is good practice...

Comment: How exactly do you check if a post is favorited?

Comment: @sdogly Uh, no that's fine...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437144/php-opening-closing-tags-performance apparently... learn new things daily!

Comment: We need to know what $fav['feed'] is equal to. Is it an integer of the feed_id or a string describing something about the feed?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question:

```
 if (isset($favourites)) {
    foreach ($favourites as $fav) { 
       // i am a favorite
    }
 } else {
       // i am not a favorite
 }
```

If you have the list of links already, which it looks like you do with `$j`:

```
foreach ($j as $jj) { 
   if (isset($favorites[$j])) { 
      // i am a favourite
   } else { 
      // i am not a favourite
   }
}
```

done.