# Efficient way to check for the existence of a single MySQL record?

Tags: php, mysql, performance

Need to perform some logic based on the existence of a record in db. Since this function will be called quite often, I'm wondering if the following can be made more efficient...

Also note that the table is an association table(employee_id and department_id together form a composite primary key), so there will only ever be one record that meets the criteria.

Ex:

```
<?php

    function checkEmpDptAssoc($employee_id, $department_id)
    {
        $sqlQuery = sprintf("SELECT COUNT(*)
                             FROM  employee_department ed
                             WHERE ed.employee_id = '%d'
                             AND   ed.department_id = '%d'",
                             $employee_id,
                             $department_id);

        $result = mysql_query($sqlQuery);
        $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

        if ((int) $row['COUNT(*)'] > 0) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;    
        } 

    }
?>
```

Comment: As well as the answers below, make sure the indices are correctly setup and appropriate reindexed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[EXISTS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) might be a little quicker since you only need to ensure one exists.

```
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM  employee_department ed
    WHERE ed.employee_id = '%d'
        AND   ed.department_id = '%d'
)
```

Comment: DUAL? Is that some Oracle stuff?

Comment: @eysikal Supported in MySQL, but you can leave it out.

Comment: @eysikal WHAT have you learned? how to run simple queries harder way?

Comment: +1 - Good point about Exists, for linq I used `Any` but the idea was the same.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try:

```
"SELECT ed.employee_id
 FROM  employee_department ed
 WHERE ed.employee_id = '%d'
 AND   ed.department_id = '%d'
 LIMIT 1"
```

Since you just need to check if a single record exists, then perhaps:

```
if (!empty($row)) {
    return TRUE;
} else {
    return FALSE;
}
```

[edit: based on @ColShrapnel's comment, which I had sadly forgotten]

```
# instead of above if...else condition:
return empty($row);
```

Sorry, I don't have the time to test this right now, but what I can say is that if you want the performance to improve (putting aside `count()` vs `limit`), start with seeing if you can add an index for a column or both columns in your where clause, being `employee_id` and `department_id`.. If `employee_id` is supposed to be unique, make it a unique index for example:

```sql
-- non unique    
create index idx_employeeid on table(employee_department)

-- unique
create unique index idx_employeeid_unq on table(employee_department)
```

Comment: Think this will be faster than a count?

Comment: @eysikal, I apologize, I'm unable to test the speed comparison between `limit` and `count` in this case.. perhaps other more experienced guys here will be able to tell you..

Comment: Actually, the two fields together make up a composite primary key - this being an association table.

Comment: Saw your edit.. If there's only one record.. then you can use the __[EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html)__ command to see the results on your end, trying with the `count`, then the `limit`, then without either and just `SELECT ed.employee_id...`

Comment: FYI: `empty($row)` ALREADY returns a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

A perfect example of [what I am always talking about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437144/opening-closing-tags-performance/2437413#2437413)

A question, asked absolutely out of nowhere.
A couple of answers, regarding EVERYTHING beside the REALLY important things.
And a poor alone comment, the only sensible answer to the question.

The only thing you really have to be concerned of, is a **proper indexing**.
The rest of your question, all these syntax issues, various variants to run THE SAME query are all NOTHING.

the only improvement I can think of is just getting rid of unnecessary code.
select 1 instead of count(*) and then you can make it just

```
    return (bool)mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
```

it won't affect performance of the code but can affect performance of the coder a bit.

Comment: I was about to accept this as the best answer, except that code bit you included won't work properly.

Comment: Won't evaluate as true in the event that there's a result. False is fine.