# Multiple PHP tags

Tags: php, coding-style

This is just a general PHP question.  Does it help or hurt to have multiple `<?php  CODE   ?>` in my scripts?

I was just looking at some of my scripts and noticed that some of them have 3-4 in it.  Dont know if this is causing any slowness on my site or not :)

Comment: it stripped out my question haha.... help to have multiple <?php some code ?>

Comment: Read: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?FirstRuleOfOptimization

Comment: You can do it, but I personally like to have only 1 opening tag (and no closing)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Opening/closing tags & performance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437144/opening-closing-tags-performance)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No, it's not causing any slowness or problems. It's perfectly common to have *dozens* or *hundreds* of separate `<?php ?>` blocks in templates.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you mean multiple PHP opening & closing tags.

Like in cases you want to echo a large block of HTML markup, it is always better to close the php tag ?> and then start it again when required. For example:

```
<?php
if($ok) {
    ?> A large
    block
    HTML MarkUp text
 <?php
} //End of if($ok)
?>
```

It actually improves the speed as the control will not parse all of the above large block and simply skip to the next < ? php tag or If end point, as compared to echoing all these lines.

Comment: i personally prefer `<?php if ($ok): ?> lots of html <?php endif ?>`.  But yeah.  This works too.  :)

Comment: @cHao So, is is using some kind/variation of ternary operator? I am asking because of : in your code.

Comment: That's [PHP's alternative syntax for control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php).  `if ($x): /* stuff here */ endif;` is functionally equivalent to `if ($x) { /* some stuff here */ }`, but `endif` explicitly says "i'm closing an `if` block" (whereas `}` says "i'm closing the last open statement").  It's easier to get right, IMO.  Particularly when you're using it to output big chunks of HTML (where the start of the statement might no longer be on the screen)...or are regularly switching in and out of PHP mode.

Answer (score 2):

You can read about this at [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php).

Comment: I know this is an old comment, but I'm downvoting it because the linked doc doesn't talk about performance but only talks about the mechanics of escaping.

Answer (score 1):

no, it doesn't do any harm but if you are doing this for example:

```
<div><?php echo $x; ?></div>
```

You can use short tags (if it is enabled in your php configuration)

```
<div><? echo $x; ?></div>
```

If you want to try and reduce the number of php tags then you could even echo your html like so:

```
echo '<div>'.$x.'</div>';
```

Comment: Using shorttags is disencouraged as many servers don't have them enabled. Be safe and use the normal ones, you don't wanna have to replace them application-wide when migrating to another server without having the ability to change that particular setting.

Comment: I think the last solution is exactly the opposite of what he wants. Doing that, php interpreter will generate the whole html page and that is slower than doing only some little change. Isn't it?

Comment: I personally have never used short tags but I thought the OP might like the option.

Comment: @Robinv.G. Nothing wrong with short tags as long as you realize (1) they're not universal, so they shouldn't be used in libraries, and (2) they can cause problems when confused with XML/SGML PIs.  For sites in general, though, they're fine.  If you don't have a way to change your server's configuration, get a new server.

Comment: Did shared hosting ever cross your mind? If short tags give problems at a customer's hosting, you're the one having to replace all those short tags. No need to use them in the first place.

Comment: @Robinv.G.: No, shared hosting didn't cross my mind, cause whether it's shared *doesn't matter*. There's nothing but laziness and/or incompetence preventing a host, shared or not, from configuring PHP per site. (I do admin stuff for people offering shared hosting; it's not hard at all.) For mod_php, those tweaks can be part of the Apache config (maybe even in .htaccess)...and for CGI, most i've seen let you stick a php.ini in your site somewhere, and it'll pick that up and use it. Even if they don't, it's easy -- *really* easy, once it's set up -- for an admin to tweak a given site's settings.

Comment: -1: Stick with the standards; that's what they're there for. If one can't be bothered to type `<?php` instead of `<?`, then perhaps one needs to find a less-stressful line of work. Getting sloppy over three characters leads to [a lot of problems for the guy (or gal) who comes after you](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/coding-for-violent-psychopaths.html).

Comment: personally, I never use short tags, was just explaining that it was possible to do so.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using it embedded in html pages (and I think you are if you have multple PHP blocks), it is normal and I don't think there's a way to avoid it.

If you have an external script, there's no reason to have multiple blocks. Although I don't think it will impact performance.