# Is calling <?php multiple times inefficient?

Tags: php, performance

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Multiple PHP tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10979626/multiple-php-tags)

Is there a difference between:

```
<?php echo "n" ?>
<?php echo "i" ?>
<?php echo "g" ?>
```

and

```
<?php
    echo "t";
    echo "i";
    echo "t";
?>
```

in terms of time and resources used?

Comment: Is it the slowest part of your application?

Comment: its very very small. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437144/opening-closing-tags-performance

Comment: The speed difference will be utterly microscopic. Go with option #2 for readability.

Comment: why are you echoing out tit? That's the real question...

Comment: It was an example. I'm actually working with generating lists.

Comment: @RandomDuck.NET: doesn't matter. Is that place **proven** to be the slowest part of the application? Why have you chosen exact these lines to "optimize"?

Comment: You call functions, not tags. `<?php` just switches from echo to evaluation mode.

Comment: This isn't english.stackexchange.com. You are not helping anyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you in doubts - measure
2. Always prefer readable solution

Comment: If you think about it from the parser point of view, it really doesn't matter at all imo. Furthermore, he should be using APC (or similar) so the files don't have to be parsed for each request in the first place

Comment: @Esailija: indeed, but irrelevant. The generated opcode for both cases will be different

Comment: Well I tested with parsekit and I get exactly the same opcodes for both as I expected

Comment: @Esailija: oh right, I was thinking about newline after each `?>`, but it only appears after double-newline

Answer (score 0):

My first thought is maybe.

That being said, I used to code for a site that took thousands of hits a second, and tried both ways. I did not see any noticeable difference. I have no empirical evidence, but in my tests on a high volume site, it seems to make no difference.

Comment: It could theoretically make a nano difference IF you are not using OPCode cache. Which you should because it speeds up your php a lot. APC is also included by default in PHP6 I hear. Anyway, when using OPCode cache there is not even a theoretical difference.