# Does opening and closing php tags multiple times increases page load?

Tags: php, performance, page-load-time

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Opening/closing tags & performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437144/opening-closing-tags-performance)

This is a newbie question, but I could not find a clear answer on the net, so please don't laugh :)

1. Does opening and closing php tags ( `<? php code ?>`) **multiple times** increases page load time?
2. How about using include templatepath multiple times?

Thank you

Comment: 1. yes, by a very very very small amount ( i think it looks ugly and is harder to maintain, so only ever open and close once) 2. ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Theoretically yes, but the difference is so miniscule that in almost all cases it wouldn't matter.
2. Not sure about what you mean. If there is a possibility of a file being included multiple times, use `include_once` or `require_once`. This will prevent multiple loads and prevents errors like **'Cannot redeclare class'**. Again this is more expensive than `include` and `require`, but more stable.

*As a side note, your questions are not anything related to code, and I am sure these have already been asked and answered multiple times in SO, so please try to search/ask better next time :)*

All the best!

Comment: include(TEMPLATEPATH."/header.php"); and then use it for other files like link.php, footer.php - calling about 10 files

Comment: That doesn't have any additional performance issue. All you are doing is use a constant which contains the path to your resource files such as header, link, footer etc

Answer (score 5):

> Does opening and closing php tags (`<? php code ?>`) multiple times increases page load time?

**NO** - I'm answering even though you've accepted, because everyone deserves to know what *actually* happens.

When PHP parses a file it [tokenises everything outside of the tags as T_INLINE_HTML](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/ext/tokenizer/tokenizer.c#162).

This is [turned directly](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/Zend/zend_language_parser.y#303) into a [ZEND_ECHO](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_4/Zend/zend_compile.c#860)

Closing and re-opening a tag is *exactly* the same speed as if you were echoing the html from within a single `<?php ?>` block.

> How about using include templatepath multiple times?

Yes the more files you include, the longer it will take to load a page, especially if they have to be read from disk each time and you are not utilising various caching mechanisms.