# Having too many php tags

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Opening/closing tags & performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437144/opening-closing-tags-performance)

I am a big performance guy, and I like to have my code run as efficiently as possible. I don't know if any of you know about liquid templating, and the style of code associate with that but often times they have tags like

```
{% if | class.method == 'true' %}

    blah text

{% endif %}
```

I hate liquid, but I've kind of set up the same thing with php tags on my site.

```
<?php /*if bob is logged in */ if ($user = 'bob') { ?>

     Stuff to do and write

<?php /*end if user is bob*/ } ?>
```

I kind of like the design, the html is really easy to edit but I find that I have a lot of php tags riddles throughout my templates. Is this bad design? I mean readability is fine for me, in fact it's better, but I'm worried about whether I'm making too large of a sacrifice with the website's performance if I add all of these little tags.

Anyone know?

Comment: Performance difference is negligible.

Comment: You should be more worried about readability IMO...

Comment: [**Premature optimization is the root of all evil**](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil)

Comment: It's definitely worth it to have better readability. There are _so_ many other things you should optimize instead (for instance caching, database queries, etc.). Besides, rendering HTML through PHP rather than just having the HTML right there would be worse performance wise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not a big performance issue.  Many compiled templates simply replace template tags with PHP open and close tags (eg. Smarty).

see @h2ooooooooooooooo link

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil