# Does the quantity of <?php and ?> tags affect performance?

Tags: php, wordpress, performance, zend-framework

In my php files, I wonder if the opening and closing  tags have a performance impact.

ie.

```
<?php echo 'Hello world'; ?>
<?php echo 'Hello world'; ?>
<?php echo 'Hello world'; ?>
<?php echo 'Hello world'; ?>
<?php echo 'Hello world'; ?>
```

vs.

```
<?php
  echo 'Hello world';
  echo 'Hello world';
  echo 'Hello world';
  echo 'Hello world';
  echo 'Hello world';
?>
```

If so, what is the impact?

Comment: Not measurably.  Write code so you can read and maintain it.  Parser optimizations are micro optimizations that are not worth your time, in general.

Comment: I highly doubt it. If it does, it would be very, very minimal. Try it, put 100 of them in a file and run a loop over requesting that file 1,000,000+ times in each style to see.

Comment: I doubt there will ever be real life situations where this will be important.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Opening/closing tags & performance?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2437144/opening-closing-tags-performance)

Comment: everyone who thinks this is primarily open based is using their opinion to shut down a legit question. great job guys.

Comment: @albert: then re-open it and close it as a duplicate of the link posted directly above it. Either way, it's not good content (either poor, or duplicate, both of which are problematic on a site of this scale)...

Comment: This is one of those questions where the empirical evidence that you collect on your own machine by trying both will tell the answer.  You'll get the answer faster, and you won't have us having to close an unnecessary question.

Comment: Most of all, rather than worrying about fastest, think about which way is clearest and easiest to read.  The cost of programmer time is orders of magnitude more expensive than machine execution time.

Comment: Why the wordpress and zend framework tags? Why 2 reopen votes? The catch-all answer to any performance questions is "Use a profiler and stop guessing".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Does it have a performance impact? Yes. Simply because there is more text for the parser to parse. It must have an impact. And yes, it will have a measurable impact.

Does it have a meaningful impact? No. Not at all. You would be hard pressed to see any difference even if you had millions of them in your app. Yes, there will be more clock cycles used, but trivially...

The bigger thing is to note that the two pieces of code are not identical in general. PHP will strip a single new line after a closing `?>`, but any other characters after `?>` will render in the output. So trailing spaces or multiple newlines after `?>` will be rendered directly.

So my suggestion is ignore the performance, write the correct and more readable code (the more semantically correct code). And ignore small performance differences...

Comment: No, they'll both produce the second version, because there is no `\n` on any output.

Comment: @PhilPerry In this particular case, yes, because the newline is stripped by the parser with `?>`, but if there was a second newline or a space, then it would be rendered. Answer updated.

Comment: Pro Tip:  ```<?=``` is shorthand for ```<?php echo``` and is NOT the same as short tags.  Just putting that out there as this question touches on readability and templating.

Comment: @MobyD: they are the same (`<?="foo"?>` is literally identical to `<?php echo "foo"; ?>`). [Proof in Opcodes](http://3v4l.org/OTlqc/vld#tabs)...

Answer (score 3):

I would say consolidate inside PHP wrappers as much as possible without sacrificing readability/functionality. Unless you specifically have a reason to break *(or use)* PHP (such as to enter a decent amount of HTML), why do it?

The performance impact is minimal, and it's all server side anyway. You can test your page load times if you're really concerned, but I would wager the time it takes to test it is exponential to the actual load it would add.

Take for example:

```
<?php
  $foo = 'writing code';
  echo "<h1 class=\"hstyle4\">Hello World</h1>";
  echo "<p>I am {$foo}, specifically HTML, inside of PHP using echo.";
  echo 'but I could just as easily have broken it into html and used only what I needed.</p>';
?>
```

Versus

```
<?php $foo = 'writing code'; ?>
<h1 class="hstyle4">Hello World</h1>
<p>I am <?php echo $foo; ?>, specifically HTML, outside of PHP. It's probably a lot more readable this way, and doesn't impact the server nearly as much by parsing unnecessary code that could have easily been handled another way.</p>
```

Comment: You are "right", but probably not for the reason you think (or thought, 3 years ago when you answered).  Preface: making decisions based on the following info, and not the way the code reads, is micro-optimizing, which is the root of all evil; don't do it.  Each of these examples will translate to one `ASSIGN` instruction, and three `ECHO` instructions.  However, the first example, because it uses interpolation, also requires a string to be generated first, which is what makes it more complex. [first opcodes](https://3v4l.org/nbaNp/vld) vs [last opcodes](https://3v4l.org/aku1S/vld).