# How to create an if-else statement

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

I am trying to show a custom loaded image as an avatar if available, and if not, default to the gravatar. I'm working in Wordpress.

I don't know very much php and I can't figure out how to do an if-then statement with the php bits I have.

This here shows both images:

```
<img class="avatar" src="<?php echo $user_info->gravatar; ?>" width="90" height="90" />
<?php echo get_avatar( $user->ID, 90 ); ?><?php echo $user_info->display_name; ?>
```

But what I would like to do is something like this:

```
IF the file "$user_info->gravatar" exists, show this: 
<img class="avatar" src="<?php echo $user_info->gravatar; ?>" width="90" height="90" />

ELSE, show this: 
<?php echo get_avatar( $user->ID, 90 ); ?><?php echo $user_info->display_name; ?>
```

You can see what I mean by visiting my [staging site](http://koru2.staging.wpengine.com/koru-teacher-directory/?as=oyegigi).

Comment: See [PHP: else](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.else.php)

Answer (score 1):

Like this?

```
<?php if(file_exists($user_info->gravatar)): ?>
    <img class='avatar' src='<?php echo $user_info->gravatar; ?>' width='90' height='90' />
<?php else: ?>
   <?php echo get_avatar( $user->ID, 90 ) . $user_info->display_name; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: It is showing the gravatar image, rather than the uploaded image (you can check out the same link to see).

Comment: Then the if-then you described in your question are wrong. Try debugging your $user_info object.

Comment: Yuck!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! don't switch in, and out of PHP like that EVER!!!!  do an echo with double quotes, and single quotes inside of it with "\ if necessary.

Comment: @eyeLoveFiddle Yuck back to you, what you are suggesting makes code unreadable and hard to mantain. I prefer to loose a tiny bit as regards to performance (opening and closing php tags) than escaping quotes. The only row you can optimize the way you are suggesting is the else statement, but I just copied it from the question, since it was about if-then-else, and not optimizing the script. :)

Comment: So you want to help slow down their PHP/server engines?

Comment: Wrap html/css with php is bad practice, because the first are static content, while the latter is dynamic. Plus, the impact of opening and closing php tags is not as big as you think it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21763386/does-the-quantity-of-php-and-tags-affect-performance

Comment: @Masiorama: how would you suggest I debug? When I echo: $user_info->gravatar I get a url so I assumed that would work for if file exists... any suggestions on how I can solve this?

Comment: I don't understand: which one of the two you want to output?

Comment: Which one is the uploaded image?

Comment: '<?php echo $user_info->gravatar; ?>'  = uploaded image

'<?php echo get_avatar( $user->ID, 90 ) ?>' = gravatar from wordpress.com

Yes, I know realize that is really confusing. Sorry :-/

Comment: Then the problem is in the if statement. Answer this: if the user has no uploaded avatar, would $user_info->gravatar be set? If so, would that be empty?

Comment: If no uploaded avatar then $user_info->gravatar should check to see if the user has set a gravatar through https://en.gravatar.com - [example of gravatar.com](http://koru2.staging.wpengine.com/koru-teacher-directory/?as=oyegigi). If none is set then my site-wide default should be used - [example of my default](http://koru2.staging.wpengine.com/koru-teacher-directory/?as=tammy%40aspiregroupnc.com).

Comment: I guess you should check gravatar documentation than. I have to stress that the answers you are searching for are not related to the Question you asked.