# Is the speed of PHP affected by excessive html brackets "<?php ?>"

Tags: php, html

I am cleaning up a site for a client and coming across a lot of scenarios with excessive opening and closing of php brackets. Example as follows:

```
<?php $zip = $_GET['zip']; ?>
<?php  if ( strlen($zip) != 5 || !is_numeric($zip) ) { ?>
  <?php $zip = 90210; ?>
<?php } else { ?>
  <?php $zip = $_GET['zip']; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

In contrast to something like this:

```
<?php
  $zip = $_GET['zip'];
  if ( strlen($zip) != 5 || !is_numeric($zip) ) {
    $zip = 90210;
  } else {
    $zip = $_GET['zip'];
  }
?>
```

As you can see in the first example, each line has an opening `<?php` and closing `?>` which is not necessary as it is pure php with nothing like html in between which would necessitate closing the php statement.

I am wondering what kind of impact this has on the speed of rendering, when it repeatedly opens and closes in this fashion. I understand for a simple if statement it may be negligible, but if this is a repetitive theme site-wide, what type of speed impact might I see if I resolve these issues?

Comment: It will effect, but even sitewide it will be negligeable compared to other overheads like database access, badly written loops, etc.... more importantly though, it makes your script much harder to read for a developer if you're constantly dropping in and out of PHP

Answer (score 1):

It affect the speed it makes the php engine start and stop every time when you can you should always just open once and close it.

[Does the quantity of <?php and ?> tags affect performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21763386/does-the-quantity-of-php-and-tags-affect-performance)

Comment: Stating that it "makes the php engine start and stop" is absolutely, inequivocably false. The PHP engine runs continuously for a single file; text outside `<?php … ?>` blocks is simply emitted directly when it's encountered, as if it were a giant "print" statement.