# Static variables across all scripts/sessions php

Tags: php

On a php web page, in the beginning of the PHP code I declare and set a lot of variables which are not altered during the execution of the script.

Each time a user visits the page, the script is executed, and I guess the values of the variables are stored in the RAM ?
So if 100 visitors are visiting the page simultaneously, the same static variables are stored in the RAM 100 times ?

Is there a way to store them in the RAM only once and have the possibility to use their values in any script without declaring them in each script ? Like PHPs superglobals.

For clarities sake: the only reason I am asking this is to realize a performance increase (by not loading the same things X times in the RAM). If the way(s) to do what I ask do not save any memory or have other positive impact on performance, I see no reason to change my current approach.

Thanks !

Comment: php runs before the page is processed by the web server and then the resources are made free for another user

Comment: @LelioFaieta I know that php is running on my webserver regardless of anything, but the vars that I declare in a php script are only loaded in the memory when the script is executed. And when the script ends the resources are freed. I know. But is there a way to not load them in memory every time the script is executed, but have them permanently in memory only once ?

Comment: you know that there are no differences in terms of performance do you?

Comment: Not worth it for simple vars - but what you're talking about sounds a lot like using a Redis caching server.

Comment: What version of PHP are you running? OpCache has been enabled by default since PHP 5.5 so you probably have no reason to try and micro-optimize any further.

Comment: @LelioFaieta No I don’t know, I was wondering whether a performance optimalization was possible, but maybe the way I do it is already the best way.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus 7.0 Let me look into OpCache

Comment: Also, you completely misunderstood PHP superglobals. PHP initiates and sets them upon every single page load. `$_SERVER` is always set fresh because when I visit a page it will have different information than when you visit a page. It's not cached, it's just done for you.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Ok, I’m sorry. I indeed mean the exact opposite: something that’s initialized at boot of the server and that can be used in any script without re-initializing it.

Comment: So are you looking to simply guarantee that certain variables are always available without needing to remember to set them or define them in a file and remember to include them? If yes then do you have access to `php.ini`?

Comment: @MonkeyZeus I have access to everything, it’s a dedicated server. I saw in phpinfo that Opcache is up and running. I use php7.0. My question is not about the need to have everything available, it’s about optimizing a script. I thought (and might well be wrong) that if for example I set variables for idk 100kb at the beginning of the script and 100 users are visiting the page it would take 10mb of ram. So I thought I could store the vars only once. Is this what OpCache does ? Even if I set the vars by including a config file ? And if yes, if I change that file will changes go “live” immediately

Comment: Please see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2437413/3536236)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concept which you seem to be juggling with can be summarized as:

> Prevent memory overhead by storing and sharing PHP variables between PHP processes so that they do not have to be re-initialized per script.

The short answer is that this is simply not possible due to the scoping nature of PHP. Every time a PHP script is executed it needs to bring in a copy of the variable into it's own execution scope.

By far the biggest culprit for slowing down a server is disk access time.

If you have:

**vars.php`**

```
<?php
$var1 = 'hi';
$var2 = 20;
$var3 = 99;
```

and

**index.php**

```
<?php
require_once('vars.php');
```

then the **most** intensive part of `index.php` is reading `vars.php` from the disk.

OpCache solves the issue of reading from disk by caching the instructions of `vars.php` into memory so that next time `vars.php` is requested it can just serve up what it has in memory and give a copy to the current PHP thread.

---

There exists a [`memcache`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.memcache.php) class (and many other solutions) which can store variable values in a dedicated data bank but it requires the setup of a memcache server.

The issue is that this still will not prevent memory overhead because calling `memcache::get( 'someVar' );` still requires bringing that variable into the current memory scope so that PHP can operate on it.

---

One more thing...

Hardware is cheap, programmers are not. Unless you are running into some severe uncontrolled memory issues which are causing system crashes then it is always cheaper to add RAM than it is to have a programmer spend days trying to solve a non-issue.

However, if you are looking to contribute to PHP's actual speed and memory consumption then you'll need to learn some `C` programming and dig into the core.

Comment: `Hardware is cheap, programmers are not. ` . bang +1

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Thanks, I accepted your answer. I agree that it’s a non issue since even if the vars took 1MB of space, 1000 concurrent sessions would take only 1gb which is indeed very cheap :). So the only question which remains: OpCache is enabled by default. My “vars.php” file is altered let’s say every minute by a daemon. Is there a risk that after the daemon updated the vars.php file, the index.php file gets served an “obsolete” vars.php file through OpCache (for more than some microseconds off course I mean).

Comment: @VincentMertens tl;dr: By `php.ini`'s default settings you would be off by 1 second at most. Long version: According to your comment from earlier, you are running PHP 7.0 so I would recommend checking out your `php.ini` file and reading up on the options `opcache.validate_timestamps` and `opcache.revalidate_freq` for a better understanding.

Comment: @VincentMertens If you want to see `OpCache` in action then write a fresh PHP file containing `<?php $a = [];` followed by 10,000 lines of `$a[] = 'f';` which should equate to about 125 KB. In your web browser open the Network tab and then visit the test file and keep track of the server response time from the first invocation and subsequent invocations.